# Can we zoom in and out using views in appecelerator titanium?

Tags: view, titanium, zooming, appcelerator-mobile, pinch

Is it possible to zoom in and zoom out in a view just like using a double tap or pinch functionality? If so can we still get the same coordinates or different coordinates after zooming in?

If I have a view of height 100 and width 100 and when I click on the end of the view it obviously returns y-position as 100.

Another question  I have is after zoom using a pinch or doubletap, will it return the end y co-ordinate as 100 or will it return a different value since we zoomed-in?

If this is not possible, is there an an alternative?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can add the view to a scrollView. When you've done this you can zoom in and out by pinching.

```
var scrollView = Titanium.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth: 'auto',
    contentHeight: 'auto',

    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,

    showVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator: true,

    //Here you can determine the max and min zoom scale
    maxZoomScale: 100,
    minZoomScale: 0.1,

//With this property you can set the default zoom
    zoomScale: 1
});
```

After you create this you can add your view to it

`scrollView.add(view)`

Hope this helps!

Tjeu